# scons builder/emitter generates implicit unwanted dependency

Tags: dependencies, builder, implicit, scons, emitter

I'm using scons 2.5.1. I want to create a builder with an emitter that changes the target name, e.g.:

```
def modify_targets(target, source, env):
    target[0] = 'new_target'
    return target, source
bld = Builder(action = 'echo $TARGETS - $SOURCES',
       suffix = ".out",
       src_suffix = '.input',
       emitter = modify_targets)
env = Environment(BUILDERS = {'Foo' : bld})
env.Foo('file')
```

The dependency tree then looks like this:

```
$ scons -Q --tree=all,status
echo new_target - file.input
new_target - file.input
 E         = exists
  R        = exists in repository only
   b       = implicit builder
   B       = explicit builder
    S      = side effect
     P     = precious
      A    = always build
       C   = current
        N  = no clean
         H = no cache

[E b      ]+-.
[E     C  ]  +-SConstruct
[E     C  ]  +-file.input
[         ]  +-file.out
[  B      ]  +-new_target
[E     C  ]    +-file.input
[E     C  ]    +-/bin/echo
```

There is this implicit `file.out` which should be removed by the emitter. This is causing problems in a case when I need to create a dependency on a directory (e.g. the directory is a source). Scons then complains about `Implicit dependency 'somedir/file.out' not found, needed by target 'xyz'`. This file will never exist. How can I force the Builder not to create the implicit dependency?

Update: it seems that the Builder first creates a `SCons.Node.FS.Entry` which then remains somewhere in the cache even if it is removed from targets list by the emitter.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I checked the sources, and what you're trying to achieve isn't possible via an *Emitter*. The specified targets and sources of a Builder will always be converted to *SCons Node*s first internally. This is where the mysterious `file.out` (or `file`) comes from.

Only after this step, the Emitter gets called and gives you the opportunity to extend the list of emitted *Nodes*.

The only way I currently see is, to specify the final target name (`new_file`)  directly as `target` in your *Builder* call. In your Emitter you could then add more target nodes if needed, but the first target will always be an implicit dependency, sorry.

---

For reference, what follows is my old, and wrong, answer:

Remove the

```
suffix = ".out",
```

line from the definition of your Builder. It enforces that the output file has to end with a `.out` suffix, which is obviously not what you want in this case.

Comment: That will still create an unwanted node `file` (without the prefix).